# Eclipse Generics Issue - Workaround?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Given the following type signatures, I'm able to compile and run the code under Maven with both JDK 6 and JDK 7, but Eclipse gives a "Bound mismatch: The type F is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<F extends Field<TP,F>>` of the type `Field<TP,F>`" error in TupleVisitor.

I believe I need these types, although I understand this is difficult to motivate given the stripped-down example. Can anyone suggest a workaround that will let me continue to work in Eclipse?

```
public abstract class Tuple<F extends Field<TP, F>, TP extends Tuple<F, TP>>

public class VariableTuple<F extends Field<VariableTuple<F>, F>> extends Tuple<F, VariableTuple<F>>

public class ConstantTuple<F extends Field<ConstantTuple<F>, F>> extends Tuple<F, ConstantTuple<F>>

public class Field<TP extends Tuple<F, TP>, F extends Field<TP, F>>

public class ConstantField extends Field<ConstantTuple<ConstantField>, ConstantField>

public class VariableField extends Field<VariableTuple<VariableField>, VariableField>

public interface TupleVisitor {
  public <F extends Field<VariableTuple<F>, F>> void visit(VariableTuple<F> tuple, F field); //Eclipse error

  public <F extends Field<ConstantTuple<F>, F>> void visit(ConstantTuple<F> tuple, F field); //Eclipse error
}
```

> Filed bug at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422503
>
> No simple workaround identified. While Rohit Jain's answer wouldn't work with a visitor pattern, I took his follow-up advice and removed F as a type parameter from Field.

Comment: What is the current java compiler compliance level set for the project?

Comment: Eclipse Compliance level: JavaSE-1.6.

Comment: Maven source/target level - 1.6.

Comment: And I'll note that bumping both up to 1.7 does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you indicate where braces are for your static classes? I notice your `TupleVisitor` interface (and likewise with `ConstantField` and `VariableField`) are not generic.

Comment: They were static classes inside a test class. I've pulled them out as non-static classes into the main source root for simplicity's sake. (Same result.)

Comment: Seems to be a bug in eclipse. Couldn't find one matching this in the bug database however. May be file this one?

Comment: Filed as 422503. I'd hate to have to refactor, which is why I'm asking for a workaround, but it may be a fool's errand.

Comment: @AdamAugusta Surprisingly, if you declare the type variable `F` in the interface `TupleVisitor`, it works fine. That actually took me by surprise.

Comment: Interesting! Can you give me your full type signature for the corrected TupleVisitor? I'm not quite sure how to make it fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to a be a bug with eclipse, as it is compiling fine under javac for me too. In fact, there are few bugs related to self-referential Java generics related to eclipse that I found, but this isn't there. So, may be you should file one.

As for a workaround of this, I just found one, which I doubt you would like, as you have to make your interface generic. Yes, you heard it right. Declaring the type parameters with the interface itself, makes the code compile fine. Here's the compiling code:

```
interface TupleVisitor<E extends Field<VariableTuple<E>, E>, 
                       F extends Field<ConstantTuple<F>, F>>  {
   void visit(VariableTuple<E> tuple, E field);
   void visit(ConstantTuple<F> tuple, F field);
}
```

Of course there are two type variables, as the bounds on both of them are different. Check if this suits your need, because this really sounds to be as weird work-around, as the number of type parameters depends on the total number of implementors of `Tuple` class (Actually weird, isn't it?). Or else you have to do some other changes.

Comment: I like it. In order to let the visitor pattern work, ConstantTuple and VariableTuple have accept methods. I can simply use raw types for the accept methods and visitor implementations, doing casting upstream. Not the neatest approach, but it gets me moving again.

Comment: That's a serious caveat, but if I don't get an answer that addresses those issues, I'll accept yours. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AdamAugusta Removing generics, and falling back to casting approach is not a good one though. Still if you can refactor your classes to simplify the generic type a bit, then may be it would be easy for you. And of course you can accept the answer anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely is that type parameters are provided by the caller. Given your declarations, somebody could declare

```
class ReallyConstantField extends ConstantField {}
```

and then invoke `TupleVisitor.visit` while providing `ReallyConstantField` for `F`. The `visit` method's type constraint would then read

```
ReallyConstantField extends Field<ConstantTuple<ReallyConstantField>, ReallyConstantField>
```

so we use a `ConstantTuple<ReallyConstantField>`. The type constraint for that class would then read

```
ReallyConstantField extends Field<ConstantTuple<ReallyConstantField>, ReallyConstantField>
```

which is incorrect, as `ReallyConstantField` is a `ConstantField` which is a `Field<ConstantTuple<ConstantField>, ConstantField>`, which is an inconvertible type.

That is, even though you declare a type parameter with an `extends` bound, the only valid type argument is a single type. That is, you don't need a type parameter at all, but could simply declare:

```
void visit(ConstantTuple<ConstantField> tuple, ConstantField field);
```

**Update**

BTW, if these are supposed to be, as the example suggests, parallel class hierarchies with a one-to-one correspondence between the classes of different hierarchies, there is a simpler way to write the generics:

```
abstract class Tuple<F extends Field<TP, F>, TP extends Tuple<F, TP>> {}

class VariableTuple extends Tuple<VariableField, VariableTuple> {}

class ConstantTuple extends Tuple<ConstantField, ConstantTuple> {}

class Field<TP extends Tuple<F, TP>, F extends Field<TP, F>> {}

class ConstantField extends Field<ConstantTuple, ConstantField> {}

class VariableField extends Field<VariableTuple, VariableField> {}

interface TupleVisitor {
  public void visit(VariableTuple tuple, VariableField field);

  public void visit(ConstantTuple tuple, ConstantField field);
}
```